# Integração contínua e metodologias ágeis

Tags: engenharia-de-software, integração-contínua, metodologia-ágil

A integração contínua está **obrigatoriamente** relacionada com metodologias ágeis?

Minha dúvida é: É possível fazer integração com o objetivo de possibilitar a entrega contínua apesar de não haver nenhuma metodologia ágil no time? Óbvio que facilitaria (e muito) mas as metodologias podem ser "não necessárias"?

Comment: Depende do seu objetivo com a integração contínua. Quais benefícios o time espera a partir do uso da integração contínua? Todos commitarem continuamente para o *trunk* (ou *main*) e um pacote de release ser montado automaticamente já é de grande ajuda sim mesmo que o time ainda não tenha por exemplo testes automatizados nem product owner. Agora, fazer **entrega contínua** sem métodos ágeis é muito improvável. Você vai precisar de técnicas de engenharia e de gestão que, embora você possa dar outros nomes, elas já são bem conhecidas como "metodologias ágeis".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa é uma pergunta interessante.

A CI(Continuous Integration) define algumas regras pra realmente ser considerado como um ambiente CI de desenvolvimento. Porém, não define intrinsecamente a utilização de uma metodologia ágil.

Mas se olharmos bem sua essência, é a de entrega contínua de software, dessa forma você precisa entregar código sempre para o seu servidor de CI fazer todo o processo, desde compilar o código até rodar seus testes automatizados. Dessa forma podemos perceber que é um processo totalmente incremental, onde estamos sempre evoluindo e entregando um pouco mais do software.

Por isso podemos perceber que esse processo é muito parecido com a metodologia XP(eXtreme Programming), uma entrega incremental que tenha vários releases para verificar todas as premissas do projeto.

Se você realmente pretende seguir um ambiente CI você inevitavelmente terá que seguir essa ideia incremental, sem contar, testes, qualidade de software, etc. Coisas que eu considero serem primordiais, independente da metodologia adotada no desenvolvimento de software.

Implantar CI em um projeto não é simplismente colocar um servidor pra faze-lo, é uma mudança de paradigma para toda a equipe que tem que entregar software. Seguir suas regras fará seu time ser mais produtivo e propenso a entregar valor e se previnir de falhas.

Comment: Esse trecho "Implantar CI em um projeto não é simplismente colocar um servidor pra faze-lo, é uma mudança de paradigma para toda a equipe que tem que entregar software." merecia até destaque na resposta.